# Nested excel formula not showing expected result

Tags: excel

I am trying to achieve the following using nested excel formula;

[image]

Below is the formula which I am using, but output which I am getting is as follows

`=IF(OR(H2="Y",I2="Y"),1,IF(OR(H2="N",I2="N"),0,IF(OR(H2="Y",I2="N"),1,IF(OR(H2="",I2=""),"UNKNOWN",IF(OR(H2="",I2="N"),"UNKNOWN")))))`

Please let me know where is the mistake

[image]

Comment: you need to change your `OR` to `AND`

Comment: but you could simplify: `=IF(H2="Y",1,IF(H2="","UNKNOWN",0))` as per your logic only the value in H2 changes the output.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this right, your conditions are:

1. If either H or I equals "Y", then 1.
2. If both H and I equal "N", then 0.
3. If either H or I is blank, then "Unknown".

We might be missing a fourth option with one blank and one "Y", but I'll guess you'd want that to be "Unknown" too so condition 3 above still works.  If I'm guessing wrong, you'll have to add a fourth condition.

So try:

```
=IF(OR(H2="Y",I2="Y"),1,IF(AND(H2="N",I2="N"),0,IF(OR(ISBLANK(H2),ISBLANK(I2)),"UNKNOWN")))
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBCQe.png)

You could probably drop the last ISBLANK condition to simplify it.  Conditions 1 and 2 should encompass all possible Y/N combinations, so anything else should be unknown.

```
=IF(OR(H2="Y",I2="Y"),1,IF(AND(H2="N",I2="N"),0,"UNKNOWN"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Correction in your Formula

```
=IF(OR(A1="Y",B1="Y"),1,IF(AND(A1="N",B1="N"),0,IF(AND(A1="Y",B1="N"),1,IF(AND(A1="",B1=""),"UNKNOWN",IF(AND(A1="",B1="N"),"UNKNOWN")))))
```

You can use this to simplify it

```
=IF(A1="","UNKNOWN",IF(A1="N",0,IF(A1="Y",1)))
```

Same Results